# Half-screen details view from the bottom on click of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I want to implement some details view (using Storyboard) for my UITableView. So when the one clicks on the cell not the whole table view is hidden, but a new half-screen details view is shown from the bottom. Attaching screen of the prototype. On the screen when the one taps on Cell (in grey) the details for that cell is shown from the bottom.
Any help is appreciated!

[image: Prototype]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to this method but I will demonstrate what I have done for this sort of popupViews.

1. Create a new ViewController and set the main view color to clear and create your view with any background color and do whatever you want to do for the UI

[image]

```
import UIKit
protocol CancelToastDelegate: class {
    func removeBlurredBackgroundView()
}
class customToastVC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: CancelToastDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var messageView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    var toastMessage: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupMessageView()
        delegate?.removeBlurredBackgroundView()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0, execute: {
            self.dismissToast()
        })
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
  
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.toastMessage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "kToastMessage")
        self.messageLabel.text = self.toastMessage ?? ""
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.dismissToast()
    }
    func dismissToast(){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func setupMessageView(){
        self.messageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.messageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.appColor.customOrange.cgColor
        self.messageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}
```

Above for the popup view I dismissed in automatically but you can use your own method to dismiss by tapping a close button

2. Create an extension on a helper class or anywhere as UIViewController and implement following function

   ```
   func showPopup() {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customToastVC")
            vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   ```
3. in parent tableView you can use the extension as follows in DidSelect delegate or wherever you needed.

self.showPopup()

If you want to use a blurred view or something the use the protocol method I have used.

Hope it helps some what. no time to re-write code for your scenario just an example from my code

Comment: Thanks much @Swiosift! I'll try your suggestion and let you know the results later, thanks again :)